# Shut down my laptop when closed screen | linux mint tessa

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, shutdown

i use the last linux mint XFCE, i'd like my laptop to shut down when i close the screen. How can i achieve that ?

I've tried to uncomment and set HandleLidSwitch=poweroff in logind.conf i restarted the computer then.

I've also tried to set lid-close-ac-action & lid-close-battery-action to shutdown in  dconf editor but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and change the following line to this:

```
HandleLidSwitch=poweroff
```

You will need to run `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service` or restart your laptop to enable the setting.

Comment: I did this already but it does not work, my laptop don't stop

Comment: @user1758935 this could be a bug with your hardware. I am seeing that some people have to take additional steps. Confirm that you have `pm-utils`, `xfce4-power-manager`, and edit your post to include all of your hardware. Make, Model, chipset, graphics, usb devices, etc.

Comment: After logind.conf edit, I had to re-change laptop lid behavior in xfce4-power-manager and then it worked.